# How Do I Evaluate the Date Difference Across Daylight Saving Time (for a function that calculates what shift is working.)

Tags: php

I have the following function built for determining what shift is working on a given day.

```
public static function getShift($date, $startDate, $sequence)
    {
        $daysDiff = floor((strtotime($date) - strtotime($startDate)) / (60 * 60 * 24));
        $sequenceArray = explode(',', $sequence);
        $key = ($daysDiff % count($sequenceArray)) + 1;
        return $sequenceArray[$key - 1];
    }
```

It gets called using something like this:

```
$shift = ShiftHelper::getShift($date, '3/14/2023', '1,2,3,4');
```

If I use two dates that do not cross Daylight Saving Time, it seems to work fine. For instance, 3/14/2023 and 6/22/23 returns 1 (which is correct).  But if I cross the day where DLS occurs, such as 3/10/23 and 6/22/23, it returns 4 which is the incorrect shift.

How can I make this work without worrying about Day Light Saving Time?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue with your code and I get `1` with both dates. Can you write an exact piece of code and the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're basing your calculation on day having a certain number of seconds as opposed to the "number of days". I would wager that in most, but not all timezones, this nudges the time around enough so that it crosses the boundary and changes the shift number. I'd also wager that @aaronfc is in a timezone that doesn't, or has his default timezone set to UTC or another static offset.

The DateTime library can calculate this reliably:

```php
function getShift($date, $startDate, $sequence) {
    $epoch = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $startDate)->setTime(0,0,0);
    $cur   = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date)->setTime(0,0,0);
    $daysDiff = date_diff($epoch, $cur)->days;
    
    $sequenceArray = explode(',', $sequence);
    $key = ($daysDiff % count($sequenceArray)) + 1;
    return $sequenceArray[$key - 1];
}

var_dump(
    getShift('6/22/2023', '3/14/2023', '1,2,3,4'),
    getShift('6/22/2023', '3/10/2023', '1,2,3,4')
);
```

Output:

```
string(1) "1"
string(1) "1"
```

I would also suggest moving `explode(',', $sequence)` outside of the function so that the function is not required to know how to decode arbitrary strings.

Comment: Perfect... that solved the issue.  I used Carbon instead of DateTime (I'm using Laravel), but other than it fixed the issue perfectly.  Thank you for the explanation.  I knew it had something to do with the DLS, but I couldn't figure out why.  Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Is it possible or recommended to get the same calculation using days instead of minutes?